# React Navigation in Expo for Web - Browser Back Button Issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-native-web

I am currently building out a web application, in react native, using expo for web.

I am unsure of the best way to handle navigation, and I don't want to have a drawer navigator or a sidebar navigator in the chrome browser.

As a solution, I have built the navigator, "`NavBar.tsx`" as a separate component, and I import that component, into each of my screens:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Navigation from '../../../navigation';

import { Text, View } from '../../Themed';
import styles from './styles';

import NavTabIcon from '../NavTabIcon';

const NavBar = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <NavTabIcon onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Buildings')} />
      <NavTabIcon onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Dashboard')} />
      <NavTabIcon onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Faults')} />
      <NavTabIcon onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Historian')} />
      <NavTabIcon />
      <NavTabIcon />
    </View>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

**Here is my main question:** When I navigate around the app, then hit the back button in the chrome browser, it sends me back to my home screen every time. It isn't accounting for all the other screens that I navigated between.

Any help is much appreciated!!

**Side Question:** How does twitter handle their navigation bar? It looks like it was a separate component with functions written into each icon/button that navigate around their app (ie. `navigation.navigate(HomeScreen)` ).

I don't know if that is the best practice, so if any of you have recommendations it would be very helpful!

Also, here is a snapshot of my `linkingConfiguration.tsx` which I use to handle url endpoint navigation (I think that makes sense?):

```
import { LinkingOptions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';

import { RootStackParamList } from '../../types';

const linking: LinkingOptions<RootStackParamList> = {
  prefixes: [Linking.makeUrl('/')],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Root: {
        screens: {
          Buildings: {
            path: 'buildings',
            screens: {
              BuildingsScreen: 'Buildings',
            },
          },
          Dashboard: {
            path: 'dashboard',
            screens: {
              TabTwoScreen: 'Dashboard',
            },
          },
          Faults: {
            path: 'faults',
            screens: {
              tabThreeSceen: 'Faults',
            },
          },
          Historian: {
            path: 'historian',
            screens: {
              tabFourScreen: 'Historian',
            },
          },
        },
      },
      Modal: 'modal',
      NotFound: '404',
      
    },
  },
};

export default linking;
```

and that is called into my navigation index file:

```
export default function Navigation({
  colorScheme,
}: {
  colorScheme: ColorSchemeName;
}) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      linking={LinkingConfiguration}
      theme={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}
    >
      <RootNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was this... and it wasn't much of a solution:

In my `types.tsx` file I had my stack navigators, and navigation types declared:

```
import { BottomTabScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {
  CompositeScreenProps,
  NavigatorScreenParams,
} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

declare global {
  namespace ReactNavigation {
    interface RootParamList extends RootStackParamList {}
  }
}

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Root: NavigatorScreenParams<RootTabParamList> | undefined;
  Modal: undefined;
  NotFound: undefined;
};

export type AuthStackParamList = {
  Signin: undefined;
};

export type RootStackScreenProps<Screen extends keyof RootStackParamList> =
  NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, Screen>;

export type RootTabParamList = {
  Buildings: undefined;
  Dashboard: undefined;
  Faults: undefined;
  Historian: undefined;
};

export type RootTabScreenProps<Screen extends keyof RootTabParamList> =
  CompositeScreenProps<
    BottomTabScreenProps<RootTabParamList, Screen>,
    NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>
  >;
```

I changed RootStackParamList to everyscreen, instead of having Root, in the rootstack contain the four screens as seen below. so basically I had to dismantle my rootstacktab and put it into the RootStackParamList, effectively changing this:

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Root: NavigatorScreenParams<RootTabParamList> | undefined;
  Modal: undefined;
  NotFound: undefined;
};
```

to this:

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Buildings: undefined;
  Dashboard: undefined;
  Faults: undefined;
  Historian: undefined;
  Modal: undefined;
  NotFound: undefined;
};
```

FINAL RESULT: I ended up switching over to react router. This solution would fix one thing and break another...